# Logging a request header before Spring Security filter chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I want to log the contents of a given incoming request header as early as possible.

I know about approaches like `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` or a logging `HandlerInterceptor`, however these seem to only log after Spring has executed a lot of other code, such as the Spring Security filter chain.

I want to log *before* Spring has done any of that, as early as possible based on a single requirement: the log message needs to be able to extract a header from the HTTP request.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What's your reason for needing the log as early as possible? Is this something that would be more effectively logged at the gateway/load-balancer level?

Comment: Debugging issues that occur in Spring Security filters. When you have a huge volume of logs it gets impossible to correlate them. If we can put the correlation token in the MDC early on then all those logs will be easy to correlate with a given request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this using the embedded Tomcat. Since this receives the request before Spring does, you can capture the entire dispatched request from here.

```java
public class CustomLoggerValve extends ValveBase {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomLoggerValve.class);

    @Override
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            MDC.put("requestId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            logger.info("Received request");
            getNext().invoke(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove("requestId");
        }
    }
}
```

Since I'm using Spring without Spring Boot, I can just add this to my Tomcat directly:

```java
Tomcat tomcat = // ... your tomcat setup
tomcat.getService().getContainer().getPipeline().addValve(new CustomLoggerValve());
```

I haven't tried, but [it looks like you could add this quite easily in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/embeddedservletcontainercustomizer-configurableembeddedservletcontainer-spring-boot) too.

Presumably a similar approach would work with embedded Jetty/other JVM web servers.